# How to center and inline the text?

Tags: html, css

For my html code I am trying to inline my text and put it in the center, what's wrong?

```
div.wrapper a {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #808080;
}
```

Comment: Provide the complete context!

Comment: OP you need to provide some HTML that this CSS applies to, to tell what's going wrong.  More context please.

Answer (score 1):

You dont put the text-align on the text element itself.
If you have the structure like this:

.wrapper and inside an `<a>` or `<p>` element. than you put the text align: center on the div so everything center inside this div.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q0ouh6b9/

```
.wrapper {
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
div.wrapper a {
    // All other properties
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the anchor element to `inline`, it will not extend the full width of its element. To do what you want, apply `text-align:center` to the div element, or set the anchor to `display:block;` with a width of 100%.

The first will make all text inside the div centered while the second makes the text take up the full width and centers it within its own block.